# When does InnerHTML execute immediately?

Tags: dom, vbscript, hta

I would expect this HTA code to print `a` to be replaced some time later by `b`. However, what it does is it prints nothing for some time, and then `b`.
With the MsgBox line enabled, it does print `a` first.

It seems that the execution of `statusinfo.InnerHTML = "a"` is postponed. Can any body tell me why this is? And how would I obtain the desired behavior (immediate refresh)?

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=VBScript>
    Sub doThis()
        statusinfo.InnerHTML = "a"
        'MsgBox "stop"
        intensiveOperation
        statusinfo.InnerHTML = "b"
    End Sub

    Sub intensiveOperation()
        'takes long
    End Sub
</SCRIPT>

<BODY>
    <button onclick="doThis">Run</button>
    <div id="statusinfo">&nbsp;</div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: When you assign two different values to any variable sequentially, only the last one will be the actual value after operations. The script is run first, and after that the page is re-rendered. If you want to see `a` and `b` on page, you've to use [`setTimeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536753%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method to delay `intensiveOperation` so, that `a` is rendered before a new script is executed.

Comment: So how would my code have to be modified to get the desired result? I've tried wrapping the intensiveOperation using `retval = window.setTimeout("intensiveOperation", 2000, "VBScript")` but the only thing it does is that now `b` is shown immediately instead of after some time. Same with 2000 in place of 10. `a` is never shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scripts and rendering are executed in a single thread. This means, that `doThis` will be finished before rendering starts. In the meanwhile you've set the inner HTML to 'b', and that will be the only result you'll see.

To fix this, you've to finish the first sub, and call `intensiveOperation` with a short delay, and make the final HTML update at the end of the second sub, like so:

```
Sub doThis
    statusinfo.InnerHTML = "a"
    Call window.setTimeout(GetRef("intensiveOperation"), 4)
End Sub

Sub intensiveOperation()
    'takes long
    statusinfo.InnerHTML = "b"
End Sub
```

*Finishing* `doThis` will free the thread. Notice, that `setTimeout` **won't halt the execution**, the whole sub is executed to the end. After that browser can render the page.

`intensiveOperation` is called at some point after the rendering is finished, not earlier than the given delay, but possibly much later, depending on tasks CPU is doing at the time.

The answer to the question in the header of the question is basically: never.

Comment: Your code does demonstrate the behavior I asked For. I'd like to understand it too though. I still don't see why putting `statusinfo.InnerHTML = "b"` inside intensiveOperation() is apparently essentially different from placing it at the bottom of doThis(). What is a "script" in you definition? A Sub? So in your code two threads are in action? Why?

Comment: "Script" is "Sub", yes. There's only one thread. `doThis` is executed to its end when calling, that's why `b` needs to be moved out of the sub. `setTimeout` just delays the execution of `intensiveOperation`, it doesn't halt the sub untill `intensiveOperation` has been executed. Anything after `setTimeout` line in `doThis` would be executed before `intensiveOperation`. `setTimeout` just delays the execution of its fn argument and the delay is guaranteed only be at least 4 milliseconds, it might be much more, depending on CPU usage etc.